# Using bluetooth device to get GPS coordinates in Android/IOS Unity AR app

Tags: c#, multithreading, unity-game-engine, geolocation, augmented-reality

I'm building a Unity app that uses the ARLocation plugin/asset. It works great when I'm getting the location of the device itself, however when I connect to a bluetooth device which sends a more precise location, the camera start lagging. The lag happens exactly on the .ReadLine row (where I'm trying to get the data from the bluetooth device). The location should be updated every frame, so the problem could be that the device simply doesn't send data that often.

What I've tried to do to fix this:
-Place the method in which the ReadLine happens in a background thread and use a lock.
This caused a "Other thread trapped, signum = 6" error. I've tried to implement a lock but obviously not correctly because I still get the same error.

Here's my code:

```
public virtual void Update()
{
    if (!HasStarted)
    {
        return;
    }

    var location = ReadLocation();
    var heading = ReadHeading();

    if (location == null || heading == null)
    {
        // Debug.Log("[AbstractLocationProvider]: Null reading");
        return;
    }

    if (FirstReading)
    {
        FirstLocation = location.Value;
        CurrentLocation = FirstLocation;
        CurrentLocationRaw = FirstLocation;
        CurrentHeading = heading.Value;

        IsEnabled = true;
        FirstReading = false;

        LocationEnabled?.Invoke();
        InnerOnEnabled();

        EmitCompassUpdated();
        EmitLocationUpdated();
        EmitLocationUpdatedRaw();

        return;
    }

    UpdateLocation(location.Value);
    UpdateHeading(heading.Value);
}
```

Here I'm trying to read the gps string sent from the device:

```
protected override LocationReading? ReadLocation()
{
    if (!HasStarted)
    {
        return null;
    }

    if (Base.blAdapter.reader != null)
    {
        lock (Base.locker)
        {
            double längenString = Double.Parse(Base.lastGGAMessage.Split(",")[2].Replace(".", ",")) / 100; **//I read the gps string here**
            

            double grad = Math.Floor(längenString);
            double minuten = längenString - grad;
            double dezimalminuten = minuten / 0.6;

            double lat = dezimalminuten + grad;

            längenString = Double.Parse(Base.lastGGAMessage.Split(",")[4].Replace(".", ",")) / 100;

            grad = Math.Floor(längenString);
            minuten = längenString - grad;
            dezimalminuten = minuten / 0.6;

            double lng = dezimalminuten + grad;

            return new LocationReading()
            {
                latitude = lat,
                longitude = lng,
                altitude = double.Parse(Base.lastGGAMessage.Split(",")[9].Replace(".", ",")),
                accuracy = Base.HRMS,
                floor = -1,
                timestamp = (long)(Time.time * 1000)
            };
        }
    }
    else
    {
        var data = Input.location.lastData;
        return new LocationReading()
        {
            latitude = data.latitude,
            longitude = data.longitude,
            altitude = data.altitude,
            accuracy = data.horizontalAccuracy,
            floor = -1,
            timestamp = (long)(Time.time * 1000)
        };
    }
}
```

Here I'm trying to update the gps string to the latest data the device has sent:

```
public static void ReadMessageToEnd(System.Object o)
{
    while (Base.isConnected)
    {
        string line = null;

        try
        {
            line = Base.blAdapter.reader.ReadLine();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (line.Length > 0)
        {
            switch (line.Split(",")[0])
            {
                case "$GPGGA":
                    lock (Base.locker)
                    {
                        Base.lastGGAMessage = line; **//this is the important line**
                    }

                    if (line.Split(",")[6].Equals("0"))
                    {
                        Base.invalidFix = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Base.invalidFix = false;
                    }

                    break;

                case "@GEPOSE":
                    Base.gNeigungData = line;
                    break;

                case "$GPGST":

                    try
                    {
                        Base.VRMS = Math.Round(double.Parse(line.Split(",")[8].Replace(".", ",")), 2);
                        Base.HRMS = Math.Round(Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(double.Parse(line.Split(",")[6].Replace(".", ",")), 2) + Math.Pow(double.Parse(line.Split(",")[7].Replace(".", ",")), 2)), 2);

                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                    }

                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the Unity LogCat:

```
2023.02.06 14:42:07.596 20304 21788 Error CRASH other thread is trapped; signum = 6
0001.01.01 00:00:00.000 -1 -1 Info  --------- beginning of crash
2023.02.06 14:42:07.597 20304 21788 Error AndroidRuntime FATAL EXCEPTION: UnityMain
2023.02.06 14:42:07.597 20304 21788 Error AndroidRuntime Process: com.ld2.LD2Survey, PID: 20304
2023.02.06 14:42:07.597 20304 21788 Error AndroidRuntime java.lang.Error: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
2023.02.06 14:42:07.597 20304 21788 Error AndroidRuntime Version '2021.3.17f1 (3e8111cac19d)', Build type 'Development', Scripting Backend 'il2cpp', CPU 'arm64-v8a'
2023.02.06 14:42:07.597 20304 21788 Error AndroidRuntime Build fingerprint: 'realme/RMX2075EEA/RMX2075L1:12/RKQ1.211103.002/Q.GDPR.202211032034:user/release-keys'
2023.02.06 14:42:07.597 20304 21788 Error AndroidRuntime Revision: '0'
2023.02.06 14:42:07.597 20304 21788 Error AndroidRuntime ABI: 'arm64'
2023.02.06 14:42:07.597 20304 21788 Error AndroidRuntime Timestamp: 2023-02-06 14:42:07+0100
2023.02.06 14:42:07.597 20304 21788 Error AndroidRuntime pid: 20304, tid: 22085, name: Thread-58  >>> com.ld2.LD2Survey <<<
2023.02.06 14:42:07.597 20304 21788 Error AndroidRuntime uid: 10544
2023.02.06 14:42:07.597 20304 21788 Error AndroidRuntime signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE), fault addr --------
2023.02.06 14:42:07.597 20304 21788 Error AndroidRuntime     x0  0000000000000000  x1  0000000000005645  x2  0000000000000006  x3  0000007a2d184e60
2023.02.06 14:42:07.597 20304 21788 Error AndroidRuntime     x4  fefefefefefefeff  x5  fefefefefefefeff  x6  fefefefefefefeff  x7  7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f
2023.02.06 14:42:07.597 20304 21788 Error AndroidRuntime     x8  00000000000000f0  x9  c77d01e1ee66ea5d  x10 0000000000000000  x11 ffffff80fffffbdf
2023.02.06 14:42:07.597 20304 21788 Error AndroidRuntime     x12 0000000000000001  x13 00000000000000de  x14 0000007a2d183c60  x15 ffffffffffffffff
2023.02.06 14:42:07.597 20304 21788 Error AndroidRuntime     x16 0000007d135d0bc0  x17 0000007d135ab680  x18 0000007a2c680000  x19 0000000000004f50
2023.02.06 14:42:07.597 20304 21788 Error AndroidRuntime     x20 0000000000005645  x21 00000000ffffffff  x22 0000007c80815000  x23 0000000000000000
2023.02.06 14:42:07.597 20304 21788 Error AndroidRuntime     x24 0000007a2d185038  x25 0000007a2d188000  x26 0000007a2d188000  x27 0000000000000001
2023.02.06 14:42:07.597 20304 21788 Error AndroidRuntime     x28 000000000000004c  x29 0000007a2d184ee0
2023.02.06 14:42:07.597 20304 21788 Error AndroidRuntime     sp  0000007a2d184e40  lr  0000007d1355b99c  pc  0000007d1355b9c8
2023.02.06 14:42:07.597 20304 21788 Error AndroidRuntime 
2023.02.06 14:42:07.597 20304 21788 Error AndroidRuntime backtrace:
2023.02.06 14:42:07.597 20304 21788 Error AndroidRuntime       #00 pc 00000000000799c8  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (abort+168) (BuildId: bbbdeb7c87c74f1491f92c6e605095b0)
2023.02.06 14:42:07.597 20304 21788 Error AndroidRuntime 
2023.02.06 14:42:07.597 20304 21788 Error AndroidRuntime    at libc.abort(abort:168)
```

Obviuosly I'm not using the lock correctly. Help would be appreciated because I've been banging my head against the wall for the last three days. Also tried using ChatGPT.